# How can I change audio output device default share mode sample rate in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, audio, wasapi

I am using windows audio core api to do loopback-capture, and failed on this: 
// spClient is a smart comptr wrapped IAudioClient
hr = spClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK,iRequestedDuration, 0, &m_struWaveFormat, 0);

It returns AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT, because m_struWaveFormat is 44100,16bit format, but the configure in device property page is 48000,24bit format in share mode. If I changed this to 44100, 16 bit format, the codes aboved runs well. So, anybody can tell me how to change default share mode sample rate using audio core api please?
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the shared mode sample rate using WASAPI.

WASAPI is very low level and supports only what the underlying device supports. But even if the device supports your desired sample rate, only the administrator can change the shared mode sample rate by going into audio settings in the Control Panel.

You may however want to take a look at the Windows Registry to see if there's anything you can tweak (assuming you're running with admin privileges). Stuff in the Control Panel is often just a front end to values in the Windows Registry.

Comment: @bigbigcat were you able to change the sample rate?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I was able to find [this answer to a similar question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661489/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-windows). It's in Russian, but Google Translate worked well enough for me.